# Unable to delete project from Eclipse Oxygen workspace

Tags: eclipse, gtk, eclipse-oxygen

When trying to delete a project from Eclipse Oxygen, nothing happens and an exception is written in the logs.
I simply right-click on a project in the package explorer and I choose the 'delete' option. I am using Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a). Here is the complete build information :

```
Eclipse Platform
Version: Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)
Build id: M20171009-0410
OS: Linux, v.4.13.0-19-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.22.25
```

Here is a sample stack trace :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-12-20 12:40:25.379
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommandInContext(LegacyHandlerService.java:442)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.runCommand(LTKLauncher.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.LTKLauncher.openDeleteWizard(LTKLauncher.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.ui.actions.DeleteResourceAction.run(DeleteResourceAction.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.DeleteAction.run(DeleteAction.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5268)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4522)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4107)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourcesWizard$DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage.createControl(DeleteResourcesWizard.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.createContents(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:627)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.DeleteResourcesHandler.execute(DeleteResourcesHandler.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
        ... 44 more
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ? Or any work-around ?

Comment: Did you try to delete the eclipse cache?

Comment: `eclipse -clean` ? same exception. Refreshing project ? same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected the issue was related to the GUI, I tried running eclipse with GTK 2 instead of GTK 3. So I added the following lines to `eclipse.ini` :

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

And the problem was gone. I could again delete projects without any problem.
Here is my complete build information :

```
Eclipse Platform
Version: Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)
Build id: M20171009-0410
OS: Linux, v.4.13.0-19-generic, x86_64 / gtk 2.24.31
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has been fixed (will be in oxygen.3, I guess). It's related to resolving the "question" icon. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=528984